# <include - onclick depending the include

Tags: android, android-layout, onclick, android-databinding

I am trying to re-use a layout with buttons inside others layouts but I want the layout of the buttons to have different on click listeners for every different layout that is included. Any idea?

First layout

```
    <data>
        <variable
            name="model"
            type="com.example.calculator.viewmodel.CalculatorViewModel" />
    </data>
<include layout="@layout/buttons"
bind:var="@{model}" />
```

secondView

```
<data>
        <variable
            name="variable"
            type="com.example.calculator.viewmodel.CurrencieViewModel" />
    </data>

        <include
            layout="@layout/buttons"
            bind:currencies="@{variable}" />
```

the included layout

```
<data>
        <variable
            name="var"
            type="com.example.calculator.viewmodel.CalculatorViewModel" />

        <variable
            name="currencies"
            type="com.example.calculator.viewmodel.CurrencieViewModel" />
    </data>
...
                         <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn_0"
                android:layout_width="97dp"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:layout_row="4"
                android:layout_column="1"
                android:background="@color/white"
                android:text="0"
                android:textColor="@color/iconsColor"
                android:textSize="50dp"
                android:onClick="@{() -> depent the viewmodel different fuction"/>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is better if you use an interface for this. Something like this:

```
interface IncludedClickListener {
    void onClick();
}
```

and then inside your `included_layout.xml`:

```
<data>
    <variable
        name="clickHandler"
        type="somepackage.IncludedClickListener " />
</data>

<Button
    ...
    android:onClick="@{() -> clickHandler.onClick()"/>
```

and then modify `CurrencieViewModel` and `CalculatorViewModel` implement `IncludedClickListener`. Then use it like before:

```
<include 
    layout="@layout/buttons"
    bind:clickHandler="@{model}" />
```